# MySQL: SELECT + SUM() only returns one record

Tags: mysql, sum

Input data:

"Card" table:

cardID   Name

1          A

2          B

3          C

"Quantity" table (can have multiple entries for each card, depending on the quantity that arrived [that day]):

cardID    Quantity

1           1

1           7

3           2

3           5

3           1

The request:

```
SELECT Card.cardID, SUM(Quantity.Quantity)
FROM Card
LEFT JOIN Quantity ON Card.cardID = Quantity.cardID
GROUP BY Card.cardID WITH ROLLUP
```

returns:

cardID    SUM(...

1           ...

I need it to return:

cardID    SUM(...

1           ...

1           ...

2             0

3           ...

3           ...

3           ...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group both by Quantity and cardID.

```
SELECT Card.cardID, SUM(Quantity.Quantity)
FROM Card, Quantity
WHERE Card.cardID = Quantity.cardID
GROUP BY Card.cardID, Quantity.Quantity WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Yep, for some reasone I could not understand that interaction :).